# Android OpenGL ES 2.0 - Cannot see 3D Obect

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to render a cube using an index buffer and GLES20.glDrawElements(). No texture, I just want to keep it simple with a solid color.

However, whenever I run this all I see is a grey screen. Does anybody have any insight into what's going on?

Here are my member variables:

```
private float[] viewMatrix = new float[16];
private float[] projectionMatrix = new float[16];
private float[] modelMatrix = new float[16];

private FloatBuffer cubeVertBuffer;
private ShortBuffer cubeIndexBuffer;


private float[] MVPMatrix = new float[16];
private final int strideBytes = 3 * 4; //3 floats per vertex, 4 bytes per float
private final int positionOffset = 0;
private final int positionDataSize = 3;

private int MVPMatrixHandle = -1;
private int positionHandle = -1;
```

Here's the initialization in my renderer's constructor:

```
final float[] vertices = {
        // front
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f,
         // back
        -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f,
    };


    final short[] indices = {0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0,   // 36 of indices
            0, 3, 4, 4, 5, 0,
            0, 5, 6, 6, 1, 0,
            1, 6, 7, 7, 2, 1,
            7, 4, 3, 3, 2, 7,
            4, 7, 6, 6, 5, 4};

    cubeVertBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    cubeIndexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length * 2).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asShortBuffer();

    cubeVertBuffer.put(vertices).position(0);
    cubeIndexBuffer.put(indices).position(0);
```

And here's the three OpenGL methods I implement:

onSurfaceCreated: Calls a utility class I wrote that compiles/links the shaders and attaches the attributes passed in as attribList. I've verified that everything is compiling and that the attributes are bound.

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

    GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
    GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);

    final float eyeX = 0.0f;
    final float eyeY = 0.0f;
    final float eyeZ = 1.5f;

    final float lookX = 0.0f;
    final float lookY = 0.0f;
    final float lookZ = -5.0f;

    final float upX = 0.0f;
    final float upY = 1.0f;
    final float upZ = 0.0f;

    Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY, lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);

    final String vertexShader =
            "uniform mat4 u_MVPMatrix;            \n"

                    + "attribute vec4 a_Position; \n"

                    + "void main()                \n"
                    + "{                          \n"
                    + "  gl_Position = u_MVPMatrix * a_Position;\n"
                    + "}                          \n";

    final String fragmentShader =
            "precision mediump float;             \n"
                    + "uniform vec4 color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
                    + "void main()                \n"
                    + "{                          \n"
                    + " gl_FragColor = color;     \n"
                    + "}                          \n";

    String[] attribList = {"a_Position"};
    int programHandle = 0;
    try {
        programHandle = GLCompiler.compile(vertexShader, fragmentShader, Arrays.asList(attribList));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    MVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "u_MVPMatrix");
    positionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(programHandle, "a_Position");

    GLES20.glUseProgram(programHandle);

}
```

onSurfaceChanged:

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    final float ratio = (float) width / height;
    final float left = -ratio;
    final float right = ratio;
    final float bottom = -1.0f;
    final float top = 1.0f;
    final float near = 1.0f;
    final float far = 10.0f;

    Matrix.frustumM(projectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
}
```

onDrawFrame:

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    Matrix.setIdentityM(modelMatrix, 0);

    cubeVertBuffer.position(0);
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, strideBytes, cubeVertBuffer);
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);


    Matrix.multiplyMM(MVPMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.multiplyMM(MVPMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, MVPMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(MVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, MVPMatrix, 0);


    GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GLES20.GL_SHORT, cubeIndexBuffer);

}
```

Comment: There might be some other problems but _glDrawElements_ indices should be either GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE or _SHORT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GL_SHORT` is not a valid value for the 3rd argument of `glDrawElements()`. You need to use `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT`:

```
GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, cubeIndexBuffer);
```

Make sure that you call `glGetError()` at the end of your rendering if you encounter any unexpected behavior. It will flag these types of errors.